# Convergence of all mixed moments implies convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\mathbf X=(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)$ be a vector of random variables. For $\mathbf a=(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$, a vector of non-negative integers, let $\mathbf X^{\mathbf a}$ denote the monomial $X_1^{a_1}\dotsb X_n^{a_n}$.

Assume that $\mathbf E(\mathbf X^{\mathbf a})<\infty$ for every vector $\mathbf a$ of non-negative integers. Assume further, that the joint probability distribution of $\mathbf X$ is completely determined by the set of mixed moments $\mathbf E(\mathbf X^{\mathbf a})$ as $\mathbf a$ runs over all vectors of non-negative integers.

Now suppose $\{\mathbf X^{(k)}\}$ is a sequence of vectors of random variables, so that $\mathbf X^{(k)}=(X^{(k)}_1,\dotsc, X^{(k)}_n)$ for each $k$. Suppose that, for every vector $\mathbf a$ of non-negative integers,
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} \mathbf E(\mathbf X^{(k)\mathbf a})=\mathbf E(\mathbf X^{\mathbf a}).
$$

I believe it should follow that $\mathbf X^{(k)}$ converges to $\mathbf X$ in distribution. This would be a multivariate analogue of the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(probability_theory)) in probability theory.

Is it true? Is there a good reference to cite for it?

Comment: It is false even the single variable case There is  a crucial hypithesis in the link you gave and you did not add that to your hypothesis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, I forgot to mention that $\mathbf X$ is completely determined by its moments (of course that is crucial). I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[E K Haviland, On the Momentum Problem for Distribution Functions of More than one Variable](http://www.jstor.com/stable/2371063), American Journal of Mathematics , Jan., 1936, Vol. 58, No. 1 (Jan., 1936), pp. 164-168.

The result is found on p. 632, as Theorem 1 (The Momentum Theorem).

In fact, Haviland proves a stronger result which does not assume that the limit mixed moments determine a unique probability distribution. However, in the determinate case, his result is exactly the required result.

Comment: There is no p.632 in the given link. I guess the Theorem you cite is the only theorem in the linked paper, but why is the uniqueness implied in the determinate case?

Comment: Actyally, I think that Theorem 2 in the following article would do the job: C.Kleiber, Y. Stoyanov, Multivariate distributions and the moment problem